# SQL DB Email sending,HTML body formatting from two tables

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a sql server DB mail sending task in which the mail body should be as HTML.
Data has to be pulled from two different table.

Ex.

Table -1[Staging table-Rows keeps on adding]

```
ID      Name    C_Name

 1     john    Mumbai
 2     Adam    pune
 3     Kevin   Delhi
```

Table -2[Static table,config kind]

```
FieldID   FieldName      FieldOrder

  1      CustomerName   1
  2      City           2
```

My expected HTML mail  body is:

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td>
            CustomerName</td>
        <td>
            john</td>
        <td>
            Adam</td>
        <td>
            Kevin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            City</td>
        <td>
            Mumbai</td>
        <td>
            pune</td>
        <td>
            Delhi</td>
    </tr>
 Table rows continues....
</table>
```

HTML Table Design:

```
CustomerName John   Adam  Kevin

City         Mumbai Pune  Delhi
```

Struggling for an optimized query ,please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
create table #temp (
ID int,     Name nvarchar(20),   C_Name nvarchar(20))
insert into #temp select
 1 ,    'john'  ,  'Mumbai'
 insert into #temp select
 2 ,   'Adam'  ,  'pune' 
 insert into #temp select
 3 ,   'Kevin'   , 'Delhi'

DECLARE @Message as NVARCHAR(MAX)= '<table><tr><td>CustomerName</td>'

set @message =  @Message +(
SELECT top(1) names = STUFF((
    SELECT ' <td>' + name + '</td>'FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM #temp  AS x)

SET @Message = @Message + '</tr><tr><td>City</td>'

set @Message = @Message + (
SELECT top(1) Cities = STUFF((
    SELECT ' <td>' + #temp .C_Name  + '</td>'FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM #temp  AS x)

SET @Message = @Message + '</tr></table>' 

 select @Message 
 drop table #temp
```

Comment: @ wala rawashdeh  Appreciate your response.

`i dont want any hardcoding as below,even this has to be dynamic.
DECLARE @Message as NVARCHAR(MAX)= '<table><tr><td>CustomerName</td>'
SET @Message = @Message + '</tr><tr><td>City</td>'`

befor framing the HTML tags cant we(join query or unpivot or change vertical column to rows etc.....) and change the orientation of the temp table combining both tables as below.

`CustomerName   John    Adam  Kevin`

`City           Mumbai  Pune  Delhi`

After this framing the HTML would be simple.
please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cursors like this.

```
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @City nvarchar(50)

DECLARE @Row1 nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @Row2 nvarchar(4000)

SET @Row1 = '<tr><td>Customer Name</td>'
SET @Row2 = '<tr><td>City</td>'

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Name, C_Name 
FROM Table1

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Name, @City   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
   SET @Row1 = @Row1 + '<td>' + @Name + '</td>'
   SET @Row2 = @Row2 + '<td>' + @City + '</td>'
END   
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SET @Row1 = @Row1 + '</tr>'
SET @Row2 = @Row2 + '</tr>'

SELECT '<table>' + @Row1 + @Row2 + '</table>'
```